# Is the spectrum of a stalk a subscheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, localization

Given a scheme $X$ and a point $p \in X$, I know that $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,p})$ consists of the point $p$ together with all generic points of irreducible closed subsets containing $p$.

Can we thus view the spectrum of the stalk, $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,p})$, as an open, closed, or locally closed subscheme of $X$?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "subscheme"? Note that the canonical map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to X$ is almost never a closed immersion or an open immersion: take $X=\Bbb A^1_k$, for instance.

Comment: I see, maybe it could be a locally closed subscheme though?

Comment: The same example shows that is usually not the case: $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^1_k,p}$ is either the generic point or a closed point and the generic point, but the closed points are dense in every locally closed subscheme of a scheme of finite type over a field.

Comment: @KReiser Ah yes, that is a very good argument!

Comment: If that answers your question, I'd be happy to record it as an answer if you edit your post to make it clear that you're asking about open, closed, or locally closed subschemes.

Comment: Thank you, I just changed it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ cannot be viewed as an open, closed, or locally closed subscheme of $X$. Consider $X=\Bbb A^1_k$ for a field $k$: then $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is either the generic point, or a single closed point and the generic point topologized so that the only nontrivial open set consists of the generic point. Neither set is open nor closed in $X$, so $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ cannot be an open or closed subscheme of $X$. To see it is not a locally closed subscheme, we note that the closed points are dense in any locally closed subset of a scheme of finite type over a field, in contrast to the two spaces we found above.